# Selector file for button background

Tags: android-layout

Can anyone please provide selector file for the background of a button. The background image changes when the button is pressed. I will set custom images for the background of button. What can be the content for the drawable file  `listbackground`?

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Button 1" 
        android:background="@drawable/listbackground"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="Button 2" 
        android:background="@drawable/listbackground"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button 3" 
        android:background="@drawable/listbackground"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Button 4" 
        android:background="@drawable/listbackground"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I wanted the code for selector file for the background of button. The background image changes when we press the button. It is a custom image.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I think the question is quite clear now, what is so unclear in the question now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

listbackground.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mainfocussed"></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mainpressed"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/main"></item>

</selector>
```